# Aligning two CSS elements next to eachother

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align two div's together through using inline-block but I'm having some weird issues with this, I have tried using float and had the same problem.

Here's an example of what's going on:
[image]

They should be next to each-other but they are misaligned.

Here's my CSS:

```
#content .articlehs h3 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'New Rocker', cursive;
  background: url("../img/article_head.png") repeat-x;
  border: 2px solid background: url("../img/asbg.png") repeat-x;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#content .articlehs p {
  background: url("../img/asbg.png") repeat-x;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px;
}

#content .articlehs {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("../img/asbg.png") repeat-x;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#content .articleSidebar h3 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'New Rocker', cursive;
  background: url("../img/article_head.png") repeat-x;
  border: 2px solid background: url("../img/asbg.png") repeat-x;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

#content .articleSidebar p {
  background: url("../img/asbg.png") repeat-x;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px;
}

#content .articleSidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("../img/asbg.png") repeat-x;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

I uploaded some sample code to jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/sj851u5z/
Wondering if anyone can help me out with this as I've tried many different things with no luck :( Thanks!

Comment: To me, they are aligned... I don't understand your question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to add `vertical-align: top;` to your `#content .articlehs` declaration.

```
#content .articlehs {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("../img/asbg.png") repeat-x;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: That was quick! didn't realise it was such a simple fix, thank you very much.

Comment: **NOTE:** [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) works for inline-level and table-cell elements. It also applies to [::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) and [::first-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line).

Comment: @AndyHolmes Sorry about the delay, it wouldn't let me before but I've done it now, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to have tops of these boxes aligned, then there are a couple of things causing you problems.

You have different sizes for `margin-top` on the article and sidebar I have made these the same.

The `center` tag is unnecessary and is also pushing the type further down in the sidebar. This should be removed as it is deprecated anyway, and the `p` tags should be centered with CSS.

Though you can use `inline-block` elements to get them next to each other, I'd say floats are the better way to go here. So I have added float left to both the article and sidebar to give you the alignment.

https://jsfiddle.net/sj851u5z/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox:

```
  #content {
   display: flex;
  }

  p {
    text-align: center
  }

  #content .articlehs { 
   width: 50%;
   margin-left: 10%;
   margin-top: 10px;
  }

  #content .articleSidebar {
   width: 20%;
   margin-left: 10%;
   margin-top: 40px;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t35szgpc/1/